# How to use awk to select text from a file starting from a line number until a certain string

Tags: bash, awk, sed, tail

I have this file where I want to read it starting from a certain line number, until a string. I already used

> awk "NR>=$LINE && NR<=$((LINE + 121)) {print}" db_000022_model1.dlg

to read from a specific line until and incremented line number, but right now I need to make it stop by itself at a certain string in order to be able to use it on other files.

```
DOCKED: ENDBRANCH   7  22
DOCKED: TORSDOF 3
DOCKED: TER
DOCKED: ENDMDL
```

I want it to stop after it reaches

> DOCKED: ENDMDL

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is for extracting the pdb files from a sorted    list of scored
# ligands

mkdir top_poses

for d in $(head -20 summary_2.0.sort | cut -d, -f1 | cut -d/ -f1)
    do
    cd "$d"||continue
    # find the cluster with the highest population within the dlg
    RUN=$(grep '###*' "$d.dlg" | sort -k10 -r | head -1 | cut -d\| -f3 | sed 's/ //g')
    LINE=$(grep -ni "BEGINNING GENETIC ALGORITHM DOCKING $RUN of 100" "$d.dlg" | cut -d: -f1)
    echo "$LINE"
    # extract the best pose and correct the format
    awk -v line="$((LINE + 14))" "NR>=line; /DOCKED: ENDMDL/{exit}" "$d.dlg" | sed 's/^........//' > "$d.pdbqt"

    # convert the pdbqt file into pdb
    #obabel -ipdbqt $d.pdbqt -opdb -O../top_poses/$d.pdb
    cd ..
    done
```

When I try the

> awk -v line="$((LINE + 14))" "NR>=line; /DOCKED: ENDMDL/{exit}" "$d.dlg" | sed 's/^........//' > "$d.pdbqt"

Just like that in the shell terminal, it works. But in the script it outputs an empty file.

Comment: I didn't add the shebang part in here but it's in the script :D

Comment: I completed it.

Comment: The script works in the following way:
1. It reads a sorted list and selects the top 20
2. It enters the directory specific to each item out of the 20 
3. It reads a specific part in the $d.dlg file and outputs it into $d.pdbqt
So $d.pdbqt is created every iteration for each item in its folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your requirements for handling `DOCKED: ENDMDL` occurring before your target line:

```
awk -v line="$LINE" 'NR>=line; /DOCKED: ENDMDL/{exit}' db_000022_model1.dlg
```

or:

```
awk -v line="$LINE" 'NR>=line{print; if (/DOCKED: ENDMDL/) exit}' db_000022_model1.dlg
```

Comment: I think I have found the problem. Awk terminates based on the first DOCKED: ENDMDL in the whole file, not from the line it starts with.

Comment: Any LINE above 202 (which is where the first DOCKED: ENDMDL is present) doesn't give out anything.

Comment: I gave you 2 separate scripts and told you the difference between them was `Depending on your requirements for handling DOCKED: ENDMDL occurring before your target line`. because you didn't tell us in your question what behavior you required in that situation. Sounds like you're using the wrong script for your requirement.

Comment: I feel really stupid now.. Thank you and I'm really sorry for troubling you :D